# Убрать расширение файла, находящегося в папке при помощи .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сейчас в моем файле .htaccess прописаны такие правила (найденные в интернете)

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " (/[^?/]+)\.php"
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

И они успешно работают, если php файлы лежат в корне сайта. Но если файл test.php лежит в папке, например, folder, то это не работает. Как исправить?

Создавал второй файл .htaccess для папки /folder/, но безуспешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
RewriteEngine On
# правило срабатывает если переменная FINISH пустая
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} ^$
# и если файл действительно есть
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# и если это php скрипт
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.php$
RewriteRule .* %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,E=FINISH:1]
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. Но дело в том, что ваш код конфликтует с моим своеобразным правилом для ЧПУ

        `RewriteRule ^guides/([^/]*)$ /guide.php?hero-url=$1 [L]`

Как быть в таком случае?