# Убрать php на конце ссылки

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте, как убрать .php на конце ссылки?
Пробовал так:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " (/[^?/]+)\.php"
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Не работает

Comment: для начала, попробуйте вот тут, что получается - http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @splash58 не могу понять что к чему там

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Убрать расширение файла, находящегося в папке при помощи .htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485751/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-htaccess)

Comment: @Visman не работает

Comment: Вы за 37 секунд это выяснили? Кеш в браузере пробовали чистить для удаления лишних переадресаций там запомненных?

Comment: @Visman а что 37 секунд мало? Вполне достаточно, вставить код, сохранить и очистить кэш. Проблема решена, нужно было настроить сервер Apache.